# Liquibase log level issues and license error

Tags: liquibase

I am getting a license error in community edition when running commands:

```
2019-09-13 10:07:35 checking if license is installed
2019-09-13 10:07:35 Problem verifying the license.
net.java.truelicense.core.LicenseManagementException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

It looks everything is still working fine though, but the error does concern me a little.

First of all I was having some issues getting liquibase-3.8.0 to log anything when running commands, e.g. .\liquibase.bat update.

I eventually fixed that by adding some janino jars and log configuration to the lib folder.

```
janino-3.1.0.jar
commons-compiler-3.1.0.jar
logback.xml
```

Now I get the expected log like this:

```
2019-09-13 10:07:35 Successfully acquired change log lock
2019-09-13 10:07:36 Reading resource: file:/C:/Users/me/Downloads/liquibase-3.8.0-bin/sql/
2019-09-13 10:07:36 Reading resource: sql/me/0001_create_person_table.sql
2019-09-13 10:07:36 Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-09-13 10:07:36 Successfully released change log lock
2019-09-13 10:07:36 Liquibase: Update has been successful.
Liquibase: Update has been successful.
```

but I am also getting this error in the beginning of the log:

```
2019-09-13 10:07:35 checking if license is installed
2019-09-13 10:07:35 Problem verifying the license.
net.java.truelicense.core.LicenseManagementException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.wrap(BasicLicenseManager.java:104) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.verify(BasicLicenseManager.java:71) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.pro.license.keymgr.DaticalTrueLicenseService.licenseIsInstalled(DaticalTrueLicenseService.java:133) [liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.pro.license.keymgr.DaticalTrueLicenseService.getLicenseInfo(DaticalTrueLicenseService.java:89) [liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:196) [liquibase.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132) [liquibase.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null
        at net.java.truelicense.core.io.MemoryStore.checkedData(MemoryStore.java:65) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.io.MemoryStore.input(MemoryStore.java:42) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.V2Encryption$2$1.call(V2Encryption.java:62) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.V2Encryption$2$1.call(V2Encryption.java:58) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.crypto.BasicPbeEncryption.wrap(BasicPbeEncryption.java:63) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.V2Encryption.access$300(V2Encryption.java:25) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.V2Encryption$2.input(V2Encryption.java:58) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.V2Compression$2.input(V2Compression.java:48) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.json.codec.JsonCodec.decode(JsonCodec.java:77) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.decodeRepository(BasicLicenseManager.java:173) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.authenticate(BasicLicenseManager.java:169) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.CachingLicenseConsumerManager.authenticate(CachingLicenseConsumerManager.java:86) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.decodeLicense(BasicLicenseManager.java:165) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.CachingLicenseConsumerManager.validate(CachingLicenseConsumerManager.java:76) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager$4.call(BasicLicenseManager.java:74) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager$4.call(BasicLicenseManager.java:71) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        at net.java.truelicense.core.BasicLicenseManager.wrap(BasicLicenseManager.java:101) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Is this something I should be concerned about, or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something to be concerned about. Liquibase and Datical have recently added new expanded functionality as Liquibase Pro. This new functionality requires a paid commercial license (free trials are available). If the license is not available, you will see a message like this.

Disclaimer: I work for Datical and wrote some of the code in question, and having it dump a stack trace like that is an issue that will be addressed in future releases.